# Using js with php error

Tags: javascript, php

hey guys i have a database and am trying to fetch some result ..and i can succesfully fetch the result with php..What i need is to run the result after 3 seconds ..So i used 'setTimeout()` in js but it didnt worked out..My code

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
@$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}


$sql = 'SELECT age FROM honey';
mysql_select_db('test');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
 echo    '<script> 
 var c = 3000;
setTimeout(function() { '<?php echo $row['age'];'}, c);
 </script>';
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

The error i get is `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in C:\wamp\www\refresh\index.php on line 24` ..

how can i properl use js inside this php code..Thanx for the help

Comment: `setTimeout(function() { '<?php echo $row['age'];'}, c);` what the hell did you expect with this line?

Comment: One more point - You cannot start a php tag inside a php tag that is not closed

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't seem you've understood the difference between client and server.

The simplest way for you to accomplish this is using an xmlhttprequest ( seeing that jquery isn't linked ).

```
setInterval(function () {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            console.log('ages: ' + xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "php_ajax_handler_url_here", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}, 3000);
```

Now all you need to do is replace "php_ajax_handler_url_here" with the your php file name. And in your php all you need to do is echo your result:

```
$res = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  $res += $row['age'].' ';
}
echo $res;
```

So what does this all do? Well the client loads your html file with your js. Your js (3 seconds later) will call your php file that handles ajax responses. It will searchin your db for the information, and echo it all out as one big string.

**Update:**

[Demo without XHMLHttpRequest()](http://jsfiddle.net/gcf64xu6/1/)

I created a little library for you. I have tested it, so it should work.

So how to use the library? It's really simple.

```
 var a = age('ajax_url_handler_here').load(function(){
   console.log('done loading');
});
```

Then you start it

```
a.start(function(age){
   //do something with age
   //The callback is called every 3 seconds and updates age with new age
});
```

Then to stop

```
a.stop();
```

---

```
(function () {

    var age = function (url) {
        if (!(this instanceof age)) {
            return new age();
        }
        if(!(typeof url === 'undefined')){
            this.url = url;
        }

        this.ages = [];
        this.counter = 0;
        this.setIntervalId = -1;       

    }


    age.fn = age.prototype = {
        init: function () {}
    };
    //load unchainable
    age.fn.load = function (callback) {

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(),
              _this = this;
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                console.log('ages: ' + xmlhttp.responseText);

                //creating an array
                _this.ages = xmlhttp.responseText.split(' ');

                if(!(typeof callback === 'undefined')){
                    callback();
                }
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", this.url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        return this;
    }
  age.fn.start = function (callback) {
    this.counter = 0;
    if(this.ages.length > 0){
        var _this = this;
        this.setIntervalId = setInterval(function(){
            console.log('age: ' + _this.ages[_this.counter]);
            if(!(typeof callback === 'undefined')){
                   callback(_this.ages[_this.counter]);
            }
            _this.counter = (_this.counter + 1) % _this.ages.length;
        }, 3000);
    }

    //chainable
    return this;
};
    age.fn.stop = function(){
        if(this.setIntervalId > -1){
             clearInterval(this.setIntervalId);
             this.setIntervalId = -1;
        }

        //chainable
        return this;
    };
    window.age = age;
})();
```

**Update # 2:**

If for some reason the library did not work, feel free to try this simplified version. All you need to do is replace `var url = "url_here"` with the correct url.

Let me know if you are getting any errors.

```
var url = "url_here",
    ages = [],
    setAges = function (callback) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    console.log('Response: ' + xmlhttp.responseText);

                    //creating an array
                    ages = xmlhttp.responseText.split(' ');
                    if (!(typeof callback === 'undefined')) {
                        callback();
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log('An error occured');
                }
            };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    };

var siId = -1,
    si = function (callback) {
        var counter = 0;
        siId = setInterval(function () {
            if (!(typeof callback === 'undefined')) {
                callback(ages[counter]);
            }
            counter = (counter + 1) % ages.length;
        }, 3000);
    }


setAges(function(){
    console.log('xmlhttprequest finished starting interval');
    si(function(age){
        //do something with res
        console.log('age: ' + age);
    });
});
```

Comment: Well @Felype he wants the results directly in the js. Rather than load all the information in a hidden input or something and then get it via js (kind of annoying) he can just fetch it via ajax. To me that is simple. Now if all he wants is to just show it on the page and do nothing with it... well then I agree it's not the simplest way.

Comment: yes, just saw he wants to delay the data by 3s, i dont understand why as well, but yeah you're right.

Comment: @Grimbode yeah well it helped me but i just want 1 to display after 3 seconds and after 3 seconds i want to display 2..1 and 2 are the values of the column ,,but in the code you provide both 1 and 2 occur at the same time..

Comment: @codingbabe I see what you mean. Going to update my post to fit what you want. ;)

Comment: @Grimbode you are humble and thanx ...am waiting for your edit..:)

Comment: @codingbabe there you go

Comment: @Grimbode i have done as you said and it didnt worked ..it gives me a blank page and it didnt give me an error

Comment: @codingbabe do you have a website? Or are you doing this locally? If you do have a website do you mind giving me a link so I can check?

Comment: @Grimbode am doing it locally bro

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use client-side JS "inside" your server-side PHP. PHP is parsed and run on the server side before your client even gets (and parses and executes) the resulting JS. If you need to set a timer, you either need to do it on the server (yuck) or do it on the client (having the client issue another call to the server).

Answer (score -1):

This block:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
 echo    '<script> 
 var c = 3000;
setTimeout(function() { '<?php echo $row['age'];'}, c);
 </script>';
}
```

Will output something like this:

```
<script> 
    var c = 3000;
    setTimeout(function() { '<?php echo $row['age'];' }, c);
    setTimeout(function() { '<?php echo $row['age'];' }, c);
    setTimeout(function() { '<?php echo $row['age'];' }, c);
    setTimeout(function() { '<?php echo $row['age'];' }, c);
    setTimeout(function() { '<?php echo $row['age'];' }, c);
    setTimeout(function() { '<?php echo $row['age'];' }, c); // repeats as long as you have rows.
    // #JavascriptObviousErrorIsObvious.
</script>
```

PHP code is interpreted in serverside, you're printing your php code inside javascript and it won't execute. the most you could 'fix it is to type something like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo    "<script> 
    var c = 3000;
    setTimeout(function() { document.write('".$row['age']."'); }, c);
    </script>";
}
```

Which will output something like:

```
<script> 
    var c = 3000;
    setTimeout(function() { document.write('18'); }, c);
    setTimeout(function() { document.write('26'); }, c);
    setTimeout(function() { document.write('47'); }, c);
    setTimeout(function() { document.write('23'); }, c);
    setTimeout(function() { document.write('32'); }, c);
</script>
```

Comment: nope the answer you have given is wrong cuz i always get a parse error when i mix the js code with php

Comment: Changed it. Concatenate strings the usual way instead of nesting quotation marks may work.
Also, there is another answer here that looks fairly good as well, but know your php code runs remotely and you cannot add it inside javascript, for it won't execute, you can at most add javascript inside your php code.

Comment: Take a time to read and notice both 1st and 2nd code blocks are examples of why the code you provided is wrong. The 3rd and 4 blocks show respectively how you could fix it and the final output in the served page.
Also, reinforcing what me and everyone else said, you can't put PHP code inside javascript blocks, you can at most put PHP variable values into them, javascript blocks will always run client-side after all PHP code have been parsed and executed.